# Validar fecha Python

Tags: python, django

requiero validar una fecha que me llega desde el front y decir que sea mayor de 13 años ya tengo el codigo
lo unico que me falta es lo que va dentro del if gracias por su ayuda.

```
"""Validators functions."""
import datetime


class LegalAgeValidator:
    LEGAL_BASE_AGE = 13
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_age = LEGAL_BASE_AGE

    def __call__(self, value): 
        if  
            message = 'age not allowed to register.' % self.base_age
            raise serializers.ValidationError(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en general creo que este tipo de respuestas tan cortas deben dejarse en los comentarios voy a ajustar tu código explicando un par de detalles:

**LEGAL_BASE_AGE = 13** fue declarado como un atributo de la clase. Esto quiere decir que se accesa usando el nombre de la clase así: `LegalAgeValidator.LEGAL_BASE_AGE` y todas las instancias de la misma contarán con el.
Nota en este caso no se usa **self** pues este está orientado a los atributos de instancia.

Como tu intensión es usar la condición en el if debes escribirlo así:

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->
def __call__(self, value): 
    if value < LegalAgeValidator.LEGAL_BASE_AGE:
        message = 'age not allowed to register.' % self.base_age
        raise serializers.ValidationError(message)
```